# convert random number 893235139 into 893,235,139

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

Generate random number display it into separated form.

for example random number is 893235139 and display it as 893,235,139.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html

Comment: so, just a number format? what does this have to do with random number? and always 9 digit? if you want help, you need to give us more information

Comment: Suppose number is generated by BigInteger b = new BigInteger(256, new Random()); now i have to display b in above mention form b contains 893235139 , sop(b); will print same but i wanto print it as 893,235,139

Comment: NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(893235139); i am looking for this . thanks for comments

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, you need to use NumberFormat:

```
    NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(893235139);
```

Another way to do this is use DecimalFormat:

```
    DecimalFormat numFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###");
    String  number = numFormat.format(893235139);
```

in both case, the output will be : `893,235,139`